# Strange URL Request, any idea of what they are up to?

Tags: nginx

Today as I was reviewing the logs of my webserver, I came upon this strange request:

```
"GET /forums/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Result:+%E8%F1%EF%EE%EB%FC%E7%EE%E2%E0%ED+%ED%E8%EA%ED%E5%E9%EC+%22Appeveneomi%22;+%E2%F5%EE%E4+%E2+%E0%EA%EA%E0%F3%ED%F2+%ED%E5+%F3%E4%E0%EB%F1%FF;+Result:+%F0%E5%F1%F3%F0%F1+%E4%EB%FF+%EF%EE%F1%F2%E8%ED%E3%E0+%ED%E5%EF%F0%E8%E3%EE%E4%E5%ED+%28%EB%E8%E1%EE+%EE%F2%F1%F3%F2%F1%F2%E2%F3%E5%F2+%EF%EE%E4%EA%EB%FE%F7%E5%ED%E8%E5+%EA+%E8%ED%F2%E5%F0%ED%E5%F2%F3%29+Result:+%E4%E0%ED%ED%FB%E9+IP+%E7%E0%E1%E0%ED%E8%EB%E8+-+%EC%E5%ED%FF%E5%EC+%EF%F0%EE%EA%F1%E8+1+%F0%E0%E7;+%E8%F1%EF%EE%EB%FC%E7%F3%E5%EC+%EF%F0%EE%EA%F1%E8+186.93.127.145:8080;+%E8%F1%EF%EE%EB%FC%E7%EE%E2%E0%ED+%ED%E8%EA%ED%E5%E9%EC+%22lupAlcossep%22;+%ED%E5+%ED%E0%F8%EB%EE%F1%FC+%F4%EE%F0%EC%FB+%E4%EB%FF+%EE%F2%EF%F0%E0%E2%EA%E8;++Result:+%E4%E0%ED%ED%FB%E9+IP+%E7%E0%E1%E0%ED%E8%EB%E8+-+%EC%E5%ED%FF%E5%EC+%EF%F0%EE%EA%F1%E8+1+%F0%E0%E7;+%E8%F1%EF%EE%EB%FC%E7%F3%E5%EC+%EF%F0%EE%EA%F1%E8+164.77.196.78:80;+%E8%F1%EF%EE%EB%FC%E7%EE%E2%E0%ED+%ED%E8%EA%ED%E5%E9%EC+%22Appeveneomi%22;+%ED%E5+%ED%E0%F8%EB%EE%F1%FC+%F4%EE%F0%EC%FB+%E4%EB%FF+%EE%F2%EF%F0%E0%E2%EA%E8
```

Whoever or whatever it was requested it 8 times, each time from a different IP address. Does anyone have an idea of what they are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an attempt to see if you're vulnerable to an exploit. I wouldn't worry about it too much - this is what happens when you're on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

This is harmless, looks like - Russians just messed up their proxy configuration: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39729/is-this-get-request-an-exploit-attempt/39742#39742?newreg=5c476fe0c6a14371a5d49f4633026b58